# c# vsto Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEx

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

Using Visual Studio 2022
outlook 365 with IMAP account
VSTO addin.
c#
Event : newmaileX to capture every incoming email. If certain subject, then I enter text into the body.  If body is html, I find the  tag and insert after.  I have create a button on ribbon to test, and the email subject is altered and new text is in the body.
fine so far.
When the newmailex is fired, it runs my code, but sometimes it does not save the changes, and sometimes it does.

Why ?

if I add "mailItem.Save()"  this works, but I then get duplicates of the same email. Sometimes upto 10 duplicates.  Is this an IMAP thing ? Below is my code.

```
        void NewMail_Event(String entryIDCollection)
        {
            Outlook.NameSpace outlookNS = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;

            try
            {
                string sTag;
                string sBody;
                int nPos;
                sTag = "<table border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr bgcolor=\"#f5e942\"><td><font color=\"#FF0000\" size=\"4\">";
                sTag += "This email originated from outside and was not listed in our safe senders list.<br>";
                sTag += "DO NOT action, click on any links or open attachments unless you recognise the sender and know the content is safe.";
                sTag += "</font></td></tr></table><br>";
                string sSubject = null;
                string filter = "[EXTERNAL]";
                string[] sEmails = entryIDCollection.Split(',');
                foreach (string sEmail in sEmails)
                {
                    mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookNS.GetItemFromID(sEmail, Type.Missing);
                    
                    if (mailItem.Subject != null)
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("c:\\1data\\desktop\\vstolog.txt", mailItem.Subject + "\r\n");
                        if (mailItem.Subject.Length >= 10)
                        {
                            if (mailItem.Subject.ToUpper().StartsWith(filter))
                            {
                                sSubject = mailItem.Subject.Substring(filter.Length, mailItem.Subject.Length - filter.Length);
                                mailItem.Subject = sSubject;

                                sBody = mailItem.HTMLBody;

                                if (sBody.Contains("<body>") || sBody.Contains("<BODY>"))
                                {
                                    if (sBody.Contains("<BODY>"))
                                    {
                                        sBody = sBody.Replace("<BODY>", "<body>" + sTag);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sBody = sBody.Replace("<body>", "<body>" + sTag);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (sBody.Contains("<body") || sBody.Contains("<BODY"))
                                    {

                                        if (sBody.Contains("<body"))
                                        {
                                            nPos = sBody.IndexOf("<body", 0);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            nPos = sBody.IndexOf("<BODY", 0);
                                        }
                                        nPos = sBody.IndexOf(">", nPos);
                                        sBody = sBody.Insert(nPos + 1, sTag);

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sBody = sTag + sBody;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (mailItem.BodyFormat == OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML)
                                {
                                    mailItem.HTMLBody = sBody;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    mailItem.Body = sBody;
                                }
                                //mailItem.Close(OlInspectorClose.olSave);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
                    mailItem = null;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception eX)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(eX.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                if (mailItem != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
                mailItem = null;
                if (outlookNS != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlookNS);
                outlookNS = null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find similar issues described in case of IMAP profiles configured in Outlook, see [IMAP Sent Messages are duplicated and unread in Sent Items folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/imap-sent-messages-are-duplicated-and-unread-in-sent-items-folder-f9cb7d98-b6be-4740-89f8-3b7c2277a615) for more information.

I suppose you are handling the `NewMailEx` event of the Application class, not the `NewMail` one. There are several aspects in the code:

```
string[] sEmails = entryIDCollection.Split(',');
```

The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Note that this behavior has changed from earlier versions of the event when the `EntryIDCollection` contained a list of comma-delimited Entry IDs of all the items received in the Inbox since the last time the event was fired.

However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously. You should not assume that after these events fire, you'll always get a one-item increase in the number of items in the Inbox.

As a possible workaround you may try to handle the [ItemAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd) event on the target folder instead.

Comment: thanks.  Actually, I got it too work. I removed the Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem); and now the email appears with the changed subject an dtag inserted. I did see that entryIDcollection was always only 1 string, so already removed the split.

Comment: Great! Thank you for letting others know.